# Infix to Postfix using a Stack and Queue: unable to access memory c++

Tags: c++, stack, queue, postfix-notation, infix-notation

I am trying to take a string of an infixed expression and change it to postfix.

I believe most of the code should work however there is an issue with "Unable to read Memory" when Queue::enqueue(char, int) is called the program is unable to read "front" or "rear" if I change iString in the test_driver.cpp I get the same error but on Stack::empty() . I believe is an issue with associativity between the classes.

In a last ditch attempt the made the classes friends of each other but I'm not sure that is the right approach. I added all of the files below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
   * test_driver.cpp 

*******************************************************************************/
#include <iostream>
#include "Stack.h"
#include "Queue.h"
#include "EqConverter.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string inputString, resultString;
    EqConverter* testQueue= new EqConverter;

    inputString = "2+3";

    testQueue->convert_to_pf(inputString);
    resultString = testQueue->return_exp();

    cout << resultString;


 cin.get();
  delete testQueue;

  return 0;


    /*Queue* testQueue = new Queue;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        testQueue->enqueue(i, i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        cout<<testQueue->dequeue()->data<<endl;

    }

    delete testQueue;*/

  cin.get();
/*************************************************/
```

EqConverter.cpp

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Stack.h"
#include "Queue.h"
#include "EqConverter.h"

using namespace std;


EqConverter::EqConverter()
{
    Stack*op_stack = new Stack;
    Queue*exp_queue = new Queue;
}

EqConverter::~EqConverter()
{
    delete op_stack;
    delete exp_queue;
}

int EqConverter::convert_to_pf(string iString)
{
    // Function to verify whether a character is english letter or numeric digit. 
    // We are assuming in this solution that operand will be a single character

    //Begin Actual converting from infix to postfix//
    for (int i = 0; i < iString.length(); i++)
    {
        if (IsOperator(iString[i]))
        {
            while (!op_stack->empty() && op_stack->top()->data != '(' && HasHigherPrecedence(op_stack->top()->data, iString[i]))
            {
                exp_queue->enqueue(op_stack->top());
                op_stack->pop();
            }
            op_stack->push(iString[i], GetOperatorWeight(iString[i]));
        }
        // Else if character is an operand
        else if (IsOperand(iString[i]))
        {
            exp_queue->enqueue(iString[i], GetOperatorWeight(iString[i]));
        }

        else if (iString[i] == '(' || iString[i] == '[')
        {
            op_stack->push(iString[i], GetOperatorWeight(iString[i]));
        }

        else if (iString[i] == ')')
        {
            while (!op_stack->empty() && op_stack->top()->data != '(')
            {
                exp_queue->enqueue(op_stack->top());
                op_stack->pop();
            }
            op_stack->pop();
        }
    }

    while (!op_stack->empty())
    {
        exp_queue->enqueue(op_stack->top());
        op_stack->pop();
    }


    return 0;
}

bool EqConverter::IsOperand(char C)
{
    if (C >= '0' && C <= '9') return true;
    if (C >= 'a' && C <= 'z') return true;
    if (C >= 'A' && C <= 'Z') return true;
    return false;
}

// Function to verify whether a character is operator symbol or not. 
bool EqConverter::IsOperator(char C)
{
    if (C == '+' || C == '-' || C == '*' || C == '/' || C == '$' || C == '[' || C == '%')
        return true;

    return false;
}

// Function to verify whether an operator is right associative or not. 
int EqConverter::IsRightAssociative(char op)
{
    if (op == '$') return true;
    return false;
}


// Function to get weight of an operator. An operator with higher weight will have higher precedence. 
int EqConverter::GetOperatorWeight(char op)
{
    int weight = -1;
    switch (op)
    {
    case '(':
    case '[':
        weight = 0;
        break;
    case '+':
    case '-':
        weight = 1;
        break;
    case '*':
    case '/':
    case '%':
        weight = 2;
        break;
    case '$':
        weight = 3;
    }
    return weight;
}

// Function to perform an operation and return output. 
int EqConverter::HasHigherPrecedence(char op1, char op2)
{
    int op1Weight = GetOperatorWeight(op1);
    int op2Weight = GetOperatorWeight(op2);

    // If operators have equal precedence, return true if they are left associative. 
    // return false, if right associative. 
    // if operator is left-associative, left one should be given priority. 
    if (op1Weight == op2Weight)
    {
        if (IsRightAssociative(op1))
            return false;

        else
            return true;
    }
    return op1Weight > op2Weight ? true : false;
}

string EqConverter::return_exp()
{
    string pString;


    while (exp_queue->dequeue() != 0)
    {       
        pString.push_back(exp_queue->dequeue()->data);
    }

    return pString;
}


}
```

Queue.cpp

```
#include"Node.h"
#include"Queue.h"


using namespace std;

Queue::Queue()
{
    front = new Node;
    front = 0;

    rear = new Node;
    rear = 0;
}

Queue::~Queue()
{
    destroy_Queue();
    delete front;
    delete rear;
}

void Queue::destroy_Queue()
{
    Node* temp;

    while (front!=0)
    {
        temp = front;
        front = front->link;
        delete temp;

    }
}

void Queue::enqueue(char info, int order)
{
    Node* temp;
    temp = new Node;

    temp->data = info;
    temp->precedence = order;

    if (front == 0)
    {
        front = temp;
        rear = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        rear->link = temp;
        rear = rear->link;
    }
}

void Queue::enqueue(Node* newNode)
{
    newNode = new Node;

    if (front == 0)
    {
        front = newNode;
        rear = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        rear->link = newNode;
        rear = rear->link;
    }       
}

Node* Queue::dequeue()
{
    Node* temp;

    if (front != 0)
    {
        temp = front;
        front = front->link;
        return temp;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Stack.cpp

```
#include"Node.h"
#include"Stack.h"

using namespace std;

Stack::Stack()
{   
    tos = 0;
}

Stack::~Stack()
{
    destroy_Stack();
    delete tos;
}

void Stack::destroy_Stack()
{
    Node* temp;         //Pointer to delete the node

    while (tos != 0)    //delete the tos while it is not pointing to NULL
    {
        temp = tos;     //assign temp to "tos" so its link can be broken
        tos = tos->link;//advance "tos" to the node below it in the stack

        delete temp;    //Delete temp which pointed to the node of the previous "tos"

    }
}


Node* Stack::top() const
{
    if (tos==0)
        return 0;
    else
        return tos;
}

void Stack::push(char info, int rank)
{
    Node* newNode;
    newNode= new Node;  //create a new node to store incoming data
    newNode->data = info;       //storing the incoming char into the data of the new node
    newNode->precedence = rank; //synonym to store incoming numerical precdence into the new node
    newNode->link= tos; //link newNode to old "tos" 

    tos = newNode;   //Now that the link is created we can assign newNode as "tos"
}

void Stack::push(Node* newTop)
{
    newTop->link = tos;   //link new top node to old "tos"
    tos = newTop;       //Now that the link is created we can assign newTop as "tos"
}

Node* Stack::pop()
{
    if (tos == 0)
        return 0;

    Node* temp;
    temp= new Node; //Creates a temp node to store current "tos"
    temp = tos;             //pointer to keep track of "tos"
    tos = tos->link;        //Advances "tos" to what was stored under it

    return temp;            //Returns what "tos" was before advancing it
}

bool Stack::empty()
{
    if (tos == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

AND the corresponding Header files

EqConverter.h

```
#ifndef EQCONVERTER_H
#define EQCONVERTER_H

#include<string>

using namespace std;

class EqConverter {
  private:

    Stack *op_stack;
    Queue *exp_queue;

    //My functions for easier implementation
    bool IsOperand(char);
    bool IsOperator(char);
    int IsRightAssociative(char);
    int GetOperatorWeight(char);
    int HasHigherPrecedence(char, char);

  public:
    EqConverter();    // creates an Stack and Queue object using dynamic memory
    ~EqConverter();   // cleans up the Stack and Queue objects

    /* convert_to_pf ***********************************************************
    * iteratively traverses the string passed in and performs the steps of the 
    * conversion algorithm using the Stack and Queue; the conversion algorithm
    * is provided in the assignment statement.  You will need to provide a 
    * variable for the string parameter
    ***************************************************************************/
    int convert_to_pf(string);


    // returns a string of the converted postfix expression stored in exp_queue 
    string return_exp();  


    friend class Stack;
    friend class Queue;
};

#endif
```

Queue.h

```
/*******************************************************************************
* Queue.h 

*******************************************************************************/
#ifndef QUEUE_H
#define QUEUE_H

#include <iostream>
#include "Node.h"

class Queue {
  private:
    Node* front;  // pointer to the front of the queue
    Node* rear;   // pointer to the rear of the queue


  public:
    Queue();  // initializes front and rear to a null pointer
    ~Queue(); // deletes all nodes in the queue; may call destroy_Queue 

    /* The enqueue method ******************************************************
    * enqueue(char, int): creates a new node and places it at the rear of the
    *     queue, you will need to provide variables for the char/int parameters  
    * 
    * enqueue(Node*): adds the passed in Node argument to the rear of the queue; 
    *     you will need to provide a variable for the Node* parameter
    ***************************************************************************/    
    void enqueue(char, int);
    void enqueue(Node*);

    /* The pop and top methods *************************************************
    * dequeue(): disconnects and returns the node at the front of the queue.  
    *     This method also updates front to point to the new front.  If the 
    *     queue is empty, it should return the null pointer.    
    ***************************************************************************/
    Node* dequeue(); 

    // iteratively traverse the linked list that makes up the queue and deletes
    // each node 
    void destroy_Queue();

    friend class EqConverter;
};

#endif
```

Stack.h

```
/*******************************************************************************
* Stack.h 

*******************************************************************************/
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H

#include "Node.h"

class Stack {
  private:
    Node *tos;  // the pointer to the Top Of Stack (TOS)

  public:
    Stack();    // does nothing more than just initialize tos to a null pointer
    ~Stack();   // deletes all nodes in the stack; may call destroy_Stack 

    /* The push method *********************************************************
    * push(char, int): creates a new node and places it on the TOS, you will 
    *     need to provide variables for the char and int parameters  
    * 
    * push(Node*): adds the passed in Node argument to the TOS; you will need
    *     to provide a variable for the Node* parameter
    ***************************************************************************/
    void push(char, int);
    void push(Node*);


    /* The pop and top methods *************************************************
    * pop(): disconnects and returns the node at the TOS; a pointer is returned.
    *     This method also updates tos to point to the new TOS.  If the stack is
    *     empty, it should return the null pointer.
    * 
    * top(): returns a pointer to the Node at the TOS. If the stack is empty,
    *     it should return the null pointer.
    ***************************************************************************/
    Node* pop();
    Node* top() const;

    // iteratively traverse the linked list that makes up the stack and deletes
    // each node 
    void destroy_Stack();

    bool empty();

    friend class EqConverter;
};

#endif
```

Node.h

```
/*******************************************************************************
* Node.h 

*******************************************************************************/
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

struct Node {
  char data;
  int precedence;
  Node *link;

  // this overloaded operator uses a reference to a pointer variable
  bool operator < (const Node *&rhs) const {
    return this->precedence < rhs->precedence;
  }  
};

#endif
```

Comment: The constructor for `Queue` is leaking memory. Didn't read beyond that because aliens.

Comment: The C++ Standard Template Library (STL) offers both `stack` and `queue` so there is no need to reinvent the wheel. Using these will help you focus on your job.

Comment: `I am trying to take a string of an infixed expression and change it to postfix.`  Looks like you're trying to implement all sorts of "helper" data structures instead of the final goal.  If you need a stack, there is `std::stack` -- you want a queue, there is `std::queue` -- you want an infix to postfix converter, now that is what you should be coding, using the aforementioned types.

Answer (score 0):

I used valgrind with your program and it revealed some problems with your code immediately:

```
==15835== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==15835==    at 0x401ABC: Queue::enqueue(char, int) (in /home/A.Romanek/tmp/programming/so-1/main)
==15835==    by 0x4013C6: EqConverter::convert_to_pf(std::string) (in /home/A.Romanek/tmp/programming/so-1/main)
==15835==    by 0x400E9E: main (in /home/A.Romanek/tmp/programming/so-1/main)
==15835== 
==15835== Invalid read of size 8
==15835==    at 0x401ABC: Queue::enqueue(char, int) (in /home/A.Romanek/tmp/programming/so-1/main)
==15835==    by 0x4013C6: EqConverter::convert_to_pf(std::string) (in /home/A.Romanek/tmp/programming/so-1/main)
==15835==    by 0x400E9E: main (in /home/A.Romanek/tmp/programming/so-1/main)
==15835==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==15835== 
==15835== 
==15835== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==15835==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==15835==    at 0x401ABC: Queue::enqueue(char, int) (in /home/A.Romanek/tmp/programming/so-1/main)
==15835==    by 0x4013C6: EqConverter::convert_to_pf(std::string) (in /home/A.Romanek/tmp/programming/so-1/main)
==15835==    by 0x400E9E: main (in /home/A.Romanek/tmp/programming/so-1/main)
```

Seems to me the problem is related to your implementation of the Queue. It could also be related to the implementation of the Nodes that you put in the Queue.

Nevertheless, I'd recommend using `<queue>` and `<stack>` from STL. These should help you much.